# Test-Path comes back as false, even though the path is correct and the file is there?

Tags: powershell

Here is the jist of my problem.

I'm using "Get-Item Property" from a registry key. This registry key has an "uninstall" command line that has the name of the file location.   Example.

```
$uninstallstring = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |Where-Object { $_.DisplayName eq "Camtasia 2020" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $QuietUninstallString
```

Now when you look at what it passes into the uninstallstring variable, it stores the path of an executable that looks like this.

**C:\ProgramData\PackageCache\Camtasia\CamtasiaUninstall.exe" /Uninstall /Quiet**

But when you run test path (Example)

```
Test-Path -Path $uninstallstring
```

It comes back as "$False"

So I thought maybe I had to trim off the "/Uninstall /Quiet"

So I changed the Get-ItemProperty  to this. (Example)

```
$uninstallstring = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |Where-Object { $_.DisplayName eq "Camtasia 2020" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $QuietUninstallString).Trim("/Uninstall /Quiet")
```

The $uninstallstring variable is now storing this string.

**C:\ProgramData\PackageCache\Camtasia\CamtasiaUninstall.exe"**

When I run test-path again, it comes back as "$False"

But if I hard code it manually instead of using a variable, Test-Path comes back as "$True"

Can someone help out and give me a clue on what I might be forgetting?

Comment: seems like the string after trimming contains an trailing `"` which could be causing this problem. I would suggest to try with `-replace` instead of `.Trim(..)`: `'C:\ProgramData\PackageCache\Camtasia\CamtasiaUninstall.exe" /Uninstall /Quiet' -replace '(?<=\.exe).+'`

Comment: If it really has that double quote in the middle of the string I'd do `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty $QuietUninstallString).Split('"')[0]` so it splits on the double quote and takes the first part.

Comment: Does the registry value also **start** with a```"```? I ask because it looks like there's a couple of other cut & paste errors in your code (e.g. ```|Where-Object { $_.DisplayName eq "Camtasia 2020" ``` - no closing ```}``` and a missing ```-``` on ```eq```) - it would make sense for the path to the exe to be quoted with a ```"``` at the start *and* end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of typos. Try to use:

```
$uninstallstring = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "Camtasia 2020"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty QuietUninstallString).Split('"')[1]
Test-Path -Path $uninstallstring
```

This will also work with wildcard characters in the program name, e.g.

```
"Camtasia*"
"*amtasia 20*"
```

Comment: Hi, Re1ter, thanks for the help.  The path does come back as True now, but I have to ask this, what is the difference between "Trim" and "Split?"  

Was it the quotes around the path that was causing test-path to come back as "False?"

And to answer other peoples question above, yes, the registry entry does have the quotes encapsulated in the file path already.  I guess I don't understand why PowerShell has a problem with those double quotes around the path.

If I hard code the path with the quotes instead of using a variable, it comes back as "True" I guess this did not make sense to me

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.

The difference between `trim` and `split` in PowerShell is that `trim` removes whitespace from the beginning and end of a string, while `split` breaks a string into an array of strings based on a delimiter.